# Create scatter plot with unequal intervals on x-axis using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a scatter plot with unequal intervals on the X-axis using d3.js. My CSV data is shown here partially:

```
chr,pos,val
22,8947,8.58891099252
22,8978,4.65541559632
22,8996,6.33685790218
22,8997,9.00384002282
22,9006,4.39533823989
MT,9471,5.0655064583
MT,9472,7.83798949399
MT,9473,0.587797595352
MT,9474,4.6475160648
MT,9475,2.52382097771
MT,9476,7.8431366396
MT,9477,1.71519736769
MT,9478,2.61168595179
MT,9479,4.15061022346
MT,9470,7.1477707428
```

The number of `pos` values for each `chr` value may be different. In some cases, it could be 20, in others 100 and so on. I need to create a plot of `val` on the y-axis vs `chr` on the x-axis, with the x-interval for each `chr` being equal to the number of `pos` values for that `chr`. Although ordinal scale for the x-axis seems suitable here, it probably doesn't support unequal intervals. With linear scale, unequal intervals can be shown using polylinear scales, but the presence of alphabetic characters in `chr` mean no ticks are shown. Does anyone know how I can show unequal intervals in d3.js?

UPDATE:

I have some code here for the domain and ticks using a linear scale:

```
const x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(input.map((d) => { 
    if (d.chr === 'MT') {
      return 23;
    }
    if (d.chr === 'X') {
      return 24;
    }
    return d.chr;
  }))
  .range(xTicks);
```

I can't understand how to show the ticks now.With this it shows 23 and 24 instead of `MT` and `X`.

I am not sure of this part:

```
const xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom').tickValues(input.map((d) => { 
    if (d.chr === 'MT') {
      // returning a string here shows NaN
      return 23;
    }
    if (d.chr === 'X') {
      return 24;
    }
    return d.chr; 
  }));
```

Comment: Are you using any sexual chromosome here? If not, just assign the number 23 for the mitochondria and create an `if` in the ticks to display MT if the chromosome is 23. This way, you can use a linear scale with no problem.

Comment: In my current dataset, I have MT and X as two non-numeric chromosomes.

Comment: So, assign numbers to them (23 and 24) and create a condition to display the ticks as texts.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I added some code I wrote for the domain. I can't understand how to show the ticks, though. There is a method called `tickValues` for showing ticks corresponding to values in an array, but I am not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how conditionally formatting the ticks using `tickFormat` (not `tickValues`).

Suppose the data is:

```
19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24;
```

But we are going to change 23 for "X" and 24 for "MT" in the ticks. Click "run code snippet":

```js
var data = [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24];

var width = 400, height = 100;

var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("heigth", height);
 
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
 .domain(d3.extent(data))
 .range([0, width*.9]);
 
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .orient("bottom")
 .ticks(6)
 .tickFormat(function(d){
        if(d == 23){
     return "X"
 } else if(d==24){
     return "MT"
 } else {
     return d
 }
    })
    .scale(xScale);
      
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")  
    .attr("transform", "translate(20,20)")
    .call(xAxis);
```

```css
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #aaa;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I started at chromosome 19 just to save some space, but you can get the general idea.

Comment: Thank you! That worked:)..I was reading up on tickFormat later and tried it, but wasn't using it properly, and so was getting a wrong scale.